# How to remove -Virtualbox text

Tags: virtualbox, elementary

I installed Elementary Os in Virtualbox, and when i open a terminal, my current user looks like:

```
cypher@cypher -Virtualbox:~$
```

My question is, how do i remove the `-Virtualbox` text, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `hostname` man page:

```
SET NAME
       When called with one argument or with the --file option, the commands set the host name or the NIS/YP domain name.  hostname uses the sethostname(2) function, while all of the three domainname, ypdomainname and nisdomainname
       use setdomainname(2).  Note, that this is effective only until the next reboot.  Edit /etc/hostname for permanent change.

       Note, that only the super-user can change the names.

       It is not possible to set the FQDN or the DNS domain name with the dnsdomainname command (see THE FQDN below).

       The host name is usually set once at system startup in /etc/init.d/hostname.sh (normally by reading the contents of a file which contains the host name, e.g.  /etc/hostname).
```

So I'd try

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

And change it there to what you like, and then reboot.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to select it as the answer for when other people stumble upon the question

Comment: Just wait for 4 more minutes :)